# Java.util.Date: try to understand UTC and ET more

Tags: java, date, timezone

I live in North Carolina, btw, which is on the East Side. So I compile and run this code and it print out the same thing. The documentation say that java.util.date try to reflect UTC time.

```
Date utcTime = new Date();
Date estTime = new Date(utcTime.getTime() + TimeZone.getTimeZone("ET").getRawOffset());
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy h:mm a");
System.out.println("UTC: " + format.format(utcTime));
System.out.println("ET: " + format.format(estTime));
```

And this is what I get

```
UTC: 11/05/11 11:14 AM
ET: 11/05/11 11:14 AM
```

But if I go to this [website](http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/timer.pl) which try to reflect all different time, UTC and ET are different. What did I do wrong here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `getRawOffset()` is returning 0 - it does that for me for "ET" as well, and in fact `TimeZone.getTimeZone("ET")` basically returns GMT. I suspect that's not what you meant.

The best Olson time zone name for North Carolina is "America/New_York", I believe.

Note that you shouldn't just add the raw offset of a time zone to a UTC time - you should set the time zone of the formatter instead. A `Date` value doesn't really know about a time zone... it's always just milliseconds since January 1st 1970 UTC.

So you can use:

import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy h:mm a zzz");

format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
System.out.println("Eastern: " + format.format(date));

format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
System.out.println("UTC: " + format.format(date));
```

Output:

```
Eastern: 11/05/11 11:30 AM EDT
UTC: 11/05/11 3:30 PM UTC
```

I'd also recommend that you look into using `java.time` now - which is much, mnuch better than the `java.util` classes.

Comment: I have another question about time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968842/compare-the-current-est-to-2pm-est-how . You think you can help me out as well?

Comment: I want to highlight that recommendation about built-in libraries is not actual. Now we have lovely java.time API in standard JDK library.

Comment: @turbanoff: By "not actual" do you mean "no longer appropriate, 10 years later"? (I've edited the answer, but I can't really be expected to keep every one of my 35,000+ answers up to date...)

Answer (score 1):

according [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933368/java-timezone-issue-edt-vs-est) you habe to write `TimeZone.getTimeZone("ETS")` instead of `TimeZone.getTimeZone("ET")`

Answer (score 1):

TimeZone.getTimeZone("ET").getRawOffset() is returning 0 this is why

Answer (score 1):

The time zone you're looking for is `"EST"` or `"EDT"` (for Daylight time), not `"ET"`. See http://mindprod.com/jgloss/timezone.html.

Answer (score 1):

The proper abbreviation for Eastern Standard Time is "EST", not "ET".  It looks like the `getRawOffset()` method returns 0 if it is passed an unknown time zone.

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST").getRawOffset()
```

Also, when you output the `utcTime` variable, you are not outputting the UTC time.  You are outputting EST time because you live in that timezone.  From what I understand, the `Date` class internally stores the time in UTC...but when you format it in order to output it as a human-readable string, it takes the current locale/timezone into account.

Answer (score 1):

### Unknowingly, you have introduced ***two major problems*** in your code:

1. **Not using the proper timezone name**: The two/three/four letter timezone names (e.g. ET, EST, CEST etc.) are error-prone. The [proper way of naming a timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) is *Region/City* e.g. Europe/London. In most cases, the *Region* is the name of the continent to which the *City* belongs.
2. **Not using `Locale` with `SimpleDateFormat`**: A parsing/formatting type e.g. the legacy, `SimpleDateFormat` or the modern, `DateTimeFormatter` are `Locale`-sensitive and therefore you should always use a `Locale` to avoid surprises. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573) to learn more about it.

Also, note that a `java.util.Date` object is not a real Date-Time object like the [modern Date-Time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). Since it does not hold any format and timezone information, it applies the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy` and the JVM's timezone to return the value of `Date#toString` derived from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the Date-Time in a different format and timezone, you will need to use a `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the applicable timezone e.g.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm a zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);

        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));

        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
        System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    }
}
```

**A sample output:**

```
05/06/21 08:29 AM EDT
05/06/21 12:29 PM UTC
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/t2pMu8)

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

### A demo using `java.time`, the modern API:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        System.out.println(now);

        ZonedDateTime zdtUTC = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        System.out.println(zdtUTC);

        ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(zdtNewYork);
    }
}
```

**A sample output:**

```
2021-06-05T12:19:58.092338Z
2021-06-05T12:19:58.092338Z[Etc/UTC]
2021-06-05T08:19:58.092338-04:00[America/New_York]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/p5tzQC)

### Need output string in a different format?

You can use `DateTimeFormatter` for the output string in a different format e.g.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uu hh:mm a zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);

        ZonedDateTime zdtUTC = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        System.out.println(dtf.format(zdtUTC));

        ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(dtf.format(zdtNewYork));
    }
}
```

**A sample output:**

```
05/06/21 12:34 PM UTC
05/06/21 08:34 AM EDT
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/hZJY1s)

Here, you can use `yy` instead of `uu` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573).

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>