# Compare the current EST to 2PM EST? How?

Tags: java, time, timezone

So I have this piece of code that would return the current EST

```
Date easternTime = new Date();
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
return format.format(easternTime);
```

let say it return `x = 12:15PM`

I want to compare `x` to 3:00PM EST to see if x before or after 3:00PM EST, and/or is x between 3:00PM - 6:00PM EST. Is there a way to do this.

We dont have to use `java.util.date`. I take solution with `calendar` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would *definitely* do this in [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead. If you *really* want to do this with the built-in API, you need to use `Calendar` to find the local time in a particular time zone - but Joda would make it much simpler.

You'd use a [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) which is in a specific time zone, and possibly take the `LocalTime` from that to compare with some `LocalTime`s you've hard-coded (or read from a configuration file etc).

Comment: I know `Calendar` instance is particularly expensive to create. Do you think `Joda Time` is better in term of performance and resources?

Comment: @Harry: Could be - but when you say it's "particularly expensive" do you mean you've profiled/benchmarked your application and checked whether this is actually a performance problem, before worrying about it? (Joda Time may well be faster, admittedly. I'd use it for being a better API though...)

Comment: I am reading `Effective Java by Bloch`, and in `item 5`, Bloch mention about `Calendar` being particularly expensive, therefore, Bloch recommend change the variable from `local` to `static final` field to avoid object creation. So I was just wondering how Joda Time compare to Calendar. That all

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

The question uses the `java.util` date-time API which was the right thing to do using the Java standard library in 2011. In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) was released as part of the **Java 8 standard library** which supplanted the legacy date-time API and since then it is strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

Also, notice the following message on the Home-Page of [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> **Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this
> project.**

### Solution using `java.time`

You can use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to specify date-time along with its `ZoneId`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        ZonedDateTime then = now.withHour(14).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);
        System.out.println(now);
        System.out.println(then);

        // Compare
        if (now.isBefore(then))
            System.out.println(now + " is before " + then);
        else if (now.isEqual(then))
            System.out.println(now + " is equal to " + then);
        else
            System.out.println(now + " is after " + then);

        // Another ways to compare
        if (!now.isAfter(then))
            System.out.println(now + " is either before or at " + then);
    }
}
```

**Output as of now**:

```
2023-01-31T11:48:40.191880-05:00[America/New_York]
2023-01-31T14:00-05:00[America/New_York]
2023-01-31T11:48:40.191880-05:00[America/New_York] is before 2023-01-31T14:00-05:00[America/New_York]
2023-01-31T11:48:40.191880-05:00[America/New_York] is either before or at 2023-01-31T14:00-05:00[America/New_York]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ydhPnE)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Do not use three-letter timezone ID**: Note from the Java 7 `Timezone` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

> #### Three-letter time zone IDs
>
> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are
> also supported. However, **their use is deprecated** because the same
> abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, "CST"
> could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and
> the Java platform can then only recognize one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the date object instead of using a string. To compare use the method date.after and date.before.