# Java: Convert long time of day to timestamp

Tags: java, time, timestamp, long-integer, milliseconds

I have a long value that represents the time of day in milliseconds since midnight that day. i.e. 00:00:01 would be 1000.

I want to convert this to a long timestamp since the epoch - using the current System's day, month, year. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Which day? Which data type are you interested in? It's really not clear what you're asking. Also, bear in mind time zones - do you have a "time of day" in a UTC day, or in some specific time zone?

Comment: The current system day and date, sorry should have specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    final Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
    instance.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    instance.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    instance.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    instance.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    long result = instance.getTimeInMillis() + yourTime;
```

Also note that Calendar#getInstance does the following:

`Calendar cal = createCalendar(TimeZone.getDefaultRef(), Locale.getDefault());`

The resulting time will change according to the default set TimeZone (and yes it can change !). See this post: [java Timezone setDefault effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891881/java-timezone-setdefault-effects)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Date date = new Date(your_long_value);
```